# Where can you park a camper in Munich?

Tags: automobiles, germany, camping, campers, munich

I am going to Munich (Oktoberfest) tonight in my camper.

Does anyone have any suggestions on where to park/sleep in Munich? Ideally I would like to park for free. Obviously I will not be able to park in the center, but somewhere just outside, possibly near a subway station would be perfect.

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This is the site your looking for](http://www.muenchen.de/int/en/Rathaus/tourist_office/service/Caravan_info). It is the official Munich website and it lists some places where you can park your camper. A lot of them are camping grounds, but there are also some areas where you don't have to camp but where you just can leave your camper.

At the bottom of the page there are also some special places listed, that are only available during the Oktoberfest. I think this suits your best.

Comment: Do you know if the Allianz Arena camping is open this year?

Comment: OK now I've read the link to the Allianz Arena more careful and I saw that the information is quite old. Additionally, it mentions that it is closed during the Oktoberfest. I'll adapt my answer.